# How does this part of algorithm works?(K-means)

Tags: algorithm, unsupervised-learning

I can't understand the red box. what do does that `1` do before `{c(I)=j}` ?
Also how does all the algorithms work? May someone explains the to steps more clearly by one example!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1_{c^(i) = j}` means if `c^(i)` is equal to `j` the value is 1 and zero otherwise.

In summary, k-means try to solve Voronoi cells for each mean point, and then update mean of members of a cell and update Voronoi cells again. This step is repeated until there is no change in members of the cells.

Comment: Is `mu(j)` a vector? 
I am confused about `I` and `j`. what do counter these 2 letters?

Comment: @user8663682 `mu(j)` is mean of members of the cluster `j` at each step, and `c^(i)` is index of the cluster which is assigned to the point of `x_i`.